# Right approach to append class object to a list

Tags: python, list, class, object, append

Assume two classes as follows:

```
class SomeClass():

    def __init__(self):
        self.elements = []
    
    def add_element(self, arg1, arg2):
        """[summary]

        Args:
            arg1 ([type]): [description]
            arg2 ([type]): [description]
        """

        element = AnotherClass(arg1, arg2)
        self.elements.append(element)
        return element

    def also_add_element(self, element):
        """[summary]

        Args:
            element ([type]): AnotherClass instance
        """

        self.elements.append(element)


class AnotherClass():
    """[summary]

    Args:
        arg1 ([type]): [description]
        arg2 ([type]): [description]
    """

    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):

        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
```

Which is the right approach to add new items in the elements list?

```
s = SomeClass()
s.add_element(arg1, arg2)
```

**or**

```
s = SomeClass()
e = AnotherClass(arg1, arg2)
s.also_add_element(e)
```

First it seems somehow redundant because it needs to be documented twice but any opinion is appreciated.

Comment: Your class methods `.add_element(arg1, arg2)` and `.also_add_element(element)` are missing the self parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what these classes would actually do. Your example is taken far out of context to decide. There's no general rule.

Are objects of `SomeClass` meant to aggregate only objects of class `AnotherClass`, or is there a chance there will be other classes as well? What extensibility do you need to provide? Will this interface really stay as `add_element(self, arg1, arg2)`? Maybe there will be subclasses of `AnotherClass` that take different arguments in `__init__`?

Then there are some considerations about devX (developer experience), if you're dealing with creating an API that will be used by external projects, but I'd say they come second most of the time. And again, they will depend on how this interface is used.

One helpful thing to look at here would be [the Creator pattern from GRASP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)#Creator). You're trying to decide which part of the code should be assigned the responsibility of creating `AnotherClass`'s objects - and that decision depends on the objective of these classes, their interfaces, information they would need to have about each other, etc.

Before looking at [GRASP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID), I suggest you look at [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles first, especially the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle), and ensure you understand it well enough, to avoid creating a class that does far more than it should.

Comment: `SomeClass` is also meant to aggregate objects from other classes: `self.another_elements = [], self.even_other_elements = []` etc. and `add_` methods takes only the corresponding class attributes as arguments.

Comment: @BogdanTeodoru Will these objects be used outside `SomeClass`? If so, where? Would these places check more points in Creator pattern? Note, that although these principles talk about classes, the concepts behind them apply to some extent to functions too.

Comment: The aggregate objects will be used only in `SomeClass` and nowhere else.

Comment: Then I would go with the first option.

Comment: And the `docstring` will be almost the same for both `class` and `class method` but I don't think it's a bad thing, right?

Comment: Creating docstrings is a separate topic. You don't want to go into implementation details in a docstring, unless they have some important side effects, that are relevant in usage of other methods.

If you mean that arguments description sections for both `add_element` and `AnotherClass.__init__` will be the same - I wouldn't worry about it too much. Honestly, I've never given it much thought until now. I tend to put more details about the parameters the closer I am to the place, where they are used. In this case, `AnotherClass` docstring would contain more detail, in case I need to debug it.

Comment: But still: more detail doesn't mean "translating code into human language". Omit details that are unnecessary to the person that would read / use the part of the code you're documenting. Mind the usecases for which such docstring would be used. But don't overthink it - keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be more clean and simple to do the following?

```
def add_element(self, element):
    self.elements.append(element)
```

Then whenever you want to add a element you make a instance of the class and pass it.

```
s = SomeClass()
a = AnotherClass(arg1, arg2)
s.add_element(a)
```